# Receiving user input (via scanner) in a GUI Interface

Tags: java, user-interface, input, java.util.scanner

I'm using the following code I found around to display the results in an interface instead of a consol.

```
  public class Main{
    public static void main( String [] args ) throws InterruptedException  {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new JLabel(" Outout" ), BorderLayout.NORTH );

        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        TextAreaOutputStream taos = new TextAreaOutputStream( ta, 60 );
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( taos );
        System.setOut( ps );
        System.setErr( ps );


        frame.add( new JScrollPane( ta )  );

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println( i );
            Thread.sleep( 500 );
        }
    }
}
```

But at a certain step in my programm I need to receive user inputs. At the consol the program works but at the interface it doesn't seem to send the input to my program.

Btw, I'm using this part of code of my program to receive user input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
String data = input.nextLine();
```

My question is how can I make the GUI interface accepts user inputs and  not only displaying results/errors?

Comment: Take a look at [How To Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

Comment: What do you mean? The scanner coupled with system.in takes input from the console...

Comment: @Yassin, Yes I'd like to have a GUI interface-like Consol where I can see the results/errors but also able to send inputs. I wasn't looking to add a text field or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

User Swing's `JTextPane` for plane text input or `JEditorPane` more reachable input.

See some good examples here (press **Launch** button for real demo)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html